# Prevent SMS deletion when removing Google Account

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sms, google-account

Before, when I try to switch Google accounts (by removing old then adding new) my SMS got deleted. Is it possible to prevent this?

Also, if I maintain two Google accounts then later decide to remove one. Can I prevent SMS deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to remove your main Google account is to factory reset the phone which removes everything. Your best bet will be to download an app that can backup your SMS to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several apps before. This is the best stand alone [SMS backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore).